# transparent image in php

Tags: php, image

I am executing my following code for creating a transparent image but everytime it shows me black background.

kindly tell me my my fault in the code.

```
    <?php

    //set the content type
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

    //create the image
    $im = imagecreatetruecolor(250, 200);
    $black = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
    $blue = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 255);

    // Make the background transparent
    imagecolortransparent($im, $black);

    //text to draw
    $text=$_POST['text'];
    //font path
    $font = '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/droid/DroidSans.ttf';
    // Add the text
    imagettftext($im, 15, 0, 50, 50, -$blue, $font, $text);

    //view the image
    imagejpeg($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
    ?>
```

Comment: Have you ever seen jpeg being transparent?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make `jpeg` images transparent. Use `png` instead

Change below 2 lines:

```
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
```

**Update**

Reference Link: [create transparent png image](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolortransparent.php#example-3398)

Comment: Please explain why my answer received negative vote? As per stackoverflow's guidelines downvotes should be followed by valid reasoning.

Comment: jpeg is mad because no transparency :D

Comment: Yes that's why I suggested using png instead.

Comment: after changing jpeg to png, my code still didn't worked. what should I do now..???